Golang: Remove element from the slice preserving order
While writing program in Golang I wanted to remove an element under arbitrary idx of a slice and preserve ordering. Here's the signature
func removeOrdered(slice []byte, idxToRemove) []slice

Initially I wanted to make a function that just loops through all the elemenents after the removed idx and shifts them one index down. But I've found a nice alternative by Jon using more idiomatic Go in top-voted answer here:
How to delete an element from a Slice in Golang
Just for reference here's the suggested implementation:
func remove(slice []int, s int) []int {
    return append(slice[:s], slice[s+1:]...)
}

However it seems to me that there's a problem with that implementation. It produces
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
when trying to delete the last entry.
Correct me if I'm wrong.
Let's expand the original function a bit:
func remove(slice []int, s int) []int {
    restOfTheSlice := slice[s+1:]
    return append(slice[:s], restOfTheSlice...)
}

Let's now suppose argument is a slice of 8 elements. It's last valid idx 7. So restOfTheSlice starts at idx 7+1=8 which is out of bounds.
Anyway can somebody propose something better/more idiomatic or should I fall back to my original plan?

You could reference the official Go site: https://go.dev/wiki/SliceTricks, or even better use the builtin slices.Delete (also, that remove example does not panic when deleting the last element: https://go.dev/play/p/NU9YpS-IKCJ)

Yeah I got confused. In my program I passed to remove() an index right after the last valid index. Then it really triggered panic.

Bear in mind that the worst-case complexity of deleting an element from a slice is Θ(n), where n is the length of the slice. If you find yourself repeatedly performing this operation, you're likely not using the most efficient data structure for the problem at hand.

It won't cause an issue:
https://go.dev/play/p/11srv5vIFRs
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(remove([]int{1}, 0)) // -> []
}

func remove(slice []int, s int) []int {
    return append(slice[:s], slice[s+1:]...)
}


Hmmm... True. But it's rather odd. If I increase the s by one then I do get an OOB. So now I see that this is the thing that I've been observing. Strange since s+1 already is not a valid index.. you only get OOB on s+2. Anyway thx for helping

When you have the : you aren't accessing an index, you are specifying the bounds - slice[notBeforeIndex:beforeIndex], e.g. slice[3,5] is [0,1,2, |> 3, 4 <|, 5].  So slice[1:] on a single element is [0 |><|]

Alright. This makes it easier to think about it!
